# Why are setName and getName function highlighted in Intellij?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

Why the Intellij IDE act like this?

[image]

There's no warning or error and they are not used either. 
You can see the class name is gray. 
It's just a simple unused class I just defined to test the function names. Can anybody try this in Android Studio or Intellij and see if it appears in the same way?

Comment: Would it be better if it was in another color?

Comment: But these methods are not used in anywhere. Aren't they supposed to be gray?

Comment: @QYLin The name attribute is definitely in use. Otherwise you can report this to JetBrains with your IDE version details.

Comment: Aside from the colors, is there an icon or something on that line that explains what's wrong? It looks like the result of some kind of code inspection, surely it will show you the reason somewhere.

Comment: Use CTRL+click on the yellow ones, you'll see if they are used somewhere

Comment: No, there's no warning or error. They are not used either. You can see the class name is gray. It's a simple unused class I just defined to test it. Can anybody try this and see if it appears in the same way?

Comment: It is the same in at least 5 versions of IntelliJ (Yes I have 5 versions -- which I'll possibly clean up now).. It's intended afaict. First of all, anything that is `setXyyyy` format or `getXyyyy` format (camel case), will show up highlighted.. However, if it is `setXyyyZaaa` it will be greyed out.. This is because IntelliJ highlights setters and getters and convention is lower case `get` `set` with one Camel cased word.. not two..

Comment: Check the settings of Java | Declaration redundancy | **Unused declaration** inspection if there are any entry points/code patterns configured.